# How to return 2 separate lists from a single list?

Tags: python

If have this list here:

```
[25, 8, 22, 9]
```

How can I make the program create 2 seperate lists, and print them both? One should contain all the numbers less than 20, and the other needs to contain all the numbers greater than 20. The final print result should be displayed like this: `[8, 9]`, `[25, 22]`

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> predicates = lambda x:x<20, lambda x:x>20
>>> print [filter(pred, [25, 8, 22, 9]) for pred in predicates]
[[8, 9], [25, 22]]
```

Comment: if you look at the URL you'll notice you're not in http://codegolf.stackexchange.com ;) what will the teache say when he shows this? :)

Comment: Super answer! If only all answers were like this!!

Comment: @Trufa We do not know if there is a teacher or not since it was not tagged as homework.

Answer (score 4):

Use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> L = [25, 8, 22, 9]
>>> [x for x in L if x < 20]
[8, 9]
>>> [x for x in L if x > 20]
[25, 22]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a =  [25, 8, 22, 9] 
print [x for x in a if x > 20]
print [x for x in a if x < 20]
```

You use here *list comprehensions*. List comprehension looks like:

```
[ f(x) for x in a if cond(x) ]
```

That means: produce me a list that consists of `f(x)` for each element of `x` for that `cond(x)` is `True`.

In our case `f(x)`is simply `x`. And `cond(x)` is `x > 20` or `x < 20` (please note also that if you have 20s in your list, they will disappear from the result).

If it is a homework you can solve the task in more low-level way:

```
a = [25, 8, 22, 9]
list1 = []
list2 = []
for elem in a:
  if elem > 20:
     list1.append(elem)
  if elem < 20:
     list2.append(elem)
print list1
print list2
```

Here you iterate through the list and check its elements.
That elements that are greater than 20 you append to one list; and that that are lesser thatn 20 — to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Note: the assumes you want twenty in listTwo

```
listOne = [x for x in yourList if x < 20]
listTwo = [x for x in yourList if x >= 20]

print listOne
print listTwo
```

Although you should use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) you might be interested in the for loop approach if you are starting with python

```
listOne = []
listOne = []

for x in yourList:
    if x < 20:
        listOne.append(x)
    else:
        listTwo.append(x)
```

Comment: This would put numbers `==` to 20 in `listTwo` which is not correct. Change `else` to `x > 20`

Comment: @jamylak I never noticed your comment, I don't know why! I assumed he just miss worded and wanted the 20 in the lists, but we never heard back from OP so who knows... I'll edit in a warning... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
def print_split_list(raw_list, split_value):
    lower_list = [v for v in raw_list if v < split_value]
    upper_list = [v for v in raw_list if v >= split_value]
    print lower_list, upper_list

print_split_list([25, 8, 22, 9], 20)  # => [8, 9] [25, 22]
```

Comment: That may have been what he said, but I interpreted what he probably meant.  I doubt he'd just want any 20's tossed away.

Answer (score -2):

```
li = [25, 8, 22, 9]
li.sort()

for i, x in enumerate(li):
    if x > 20:
        print li[:i]
        print li[i:]
        break
```

Comment: This is O(n log n) due to the sort. Also, the loop should at least exit straight away when the printing is done